# How to parse multiple lines with megaparsec? many . many runs into space leak

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

I'd like to parse some very simple text for example,
`"abcxyzzzz\nhello\n"` into `["abcxyzzz", "hello"] :: String`.

Not looking for a simpler function to do this (like `words`) as I need to parse something more complex and I'm just laying the foundations here.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module RgParse where

import Data.Text (Text)
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char


data SimpleData = SimpleData String deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
data SimpleData' = SimpleData' [String] deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

instance ShowErrorComponent SimpleData where
  showErrorComponent = show

instance ShowErrorComponent String where
  showErrorComponent = show



simple :: Parsec String Text SimpleData
simple = do
  x <- many (noneOf (Just '\n'))
  pure $ SimpleData x

simple' :: Parsec String Text SimpleData'
simple' = do
  x <- many (many (noneOf (Just '\n')))
  pure $ SimpleData' x

example2 :: Text
example2 = "abcxyzzzz\nhello\n"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print "Simple:"
  case parse simple "<stdin>" example2 of
    Left bundle -> putStr (errorBundlePretty bundle)
    Right result -> print result
  print "Simple':"
  case parse simple' "<stdin>" example2 of
    Left bundle -> putStr (errorBundlePretty bundle)
    Right result -> print result
  print "done.."
```

The above unfortunately runs into an infinite loop / space leak upon entering `simple'` as it outputs the following:

```
Hello, Haskell!
[]
"Simple:"
SimpleData "abcxyzzzz"
"Simple':"
```

Using megaparsec-7.0.5 (not the latest 9.x.x).

Is there possibly a simpler approach to getting multiple lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `many` only to a parser that either consumes at least one token (here, one `Char`) or fails. That's because `many` works by running its argument until it fails. `many x` may consume zero tokens, so `many (many x)` breaks this requirement.

Note that a line should at least involve a terminating newline. That allows that requirement to be fulfilled.

```
oneline :: Parsec String Text String
oneline = many (noneOf (Just '\n')) <* single '\n'

manylines :: Parsec String Text [String]
manylines = many oneline

simple :: Parsec String Text SimpleData
simple = do
  x <- oneline
  pure $ SimpleData x

simple' :: Parsec String Text SimpleData'
simple' = do
  x <- manylines
  pure $ SimpleData' x
```

A looser requirement for `many p` is that any repetition of `p` must fail after a finite number of iterations (and here `p = many x` never fails), so `p` might consume nothing in some steps, but then it must be stateful so that after some repetitions it eventually consumes something or fails. But the above approximation is a pretty good rule of thumb in practice.